# Multiple tracks playing at once in foobar2000?

Tags: audio, foobar2000

I often have the urge to play a non-lyrical melody in the background, with its own volume meter, and then also start a completely different song *with* lyrics and have it on as the main background music.

Essentially, I wish I could have multiple songs playing at once in foobar2000. Is this perhaps possible already?

I have not noticed any way to start multiple instances of foobar2000 to achieve this, but even if that can be done, it doesn't sound optimal for many reasons.

Comment: I think you would have to be totally tone-deaf & arrhythmic to even consider this would ever sound good. Experiment with 2 radios, or the radio & TV simultaneously. See how long you can stand it.

Answer (score -1):

Just load the portable version up

Comment: Are you saying that the portable version can do this?  Or are you suggesting that the OP run the portable version and an installed version concurrently?  If so, do you *know* that it works, or are you just guessing?  … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.